# How to reload an html link/reference

Tags: javascript, html, page-refresh

I have the following link in my HTML file

```
<p class = "card-text"> This is a title </p>
<a href = "google.com" class = "btn btn-success" target = "_blank"> Text </a>
```

how can I have that after I click the button and go to google, every certain block of time say 30 seconds, google is refreshed/reloaded

Comment: Unless you load the google site into an iFrame you cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

- There is no general way for a page to affect the next page loaded into a browser
- There is no Google-specific method to cause the page to reload on a timer
- It is possible to do something along these things with a page loaded into an `<iframe>`, but Google set the `X-Frame-Options` to forbid third-parties loading their homepage into a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Just write an function with `window.setInterval()` and `window.open()` like this:

```js
window.setInterval(function(){
    window.open(URL, yourWindowName);
}, 30000); // Wait 30s
```

Don't forget to stop it with `clearInterval()`